# How can I save a value in this React lambda function?

Tags: reactjs

I have this React project template, it uses Spring for backend and a PostgreSQL database.
Here, I have the name of a caregiver, and what i want, is to get the id of that caregiver.
I don't know how to retrieve the id, from the findCaregiver method. When in the function, "result.id" will show the correct id, but when it returns to "handleSubmit", the initial method, the value is gone. I tried storing it in the current components' state, in a global variable, even in localStorage. But nothing works, after the function is done, the value is gone. Any ideas? Thank you!!

```
handleSubmit() {

        let name = this.state.formControls.caregiverName.value;
        let c = this.findCaregiver(name);
        console.log("id: " + c);

 findCaregiver(name) {
        return API_USERS.getCaregiverByName(name, (result, status, error) => {
            if (result !== null && (status === 200 || status === 201)) {
                console.log("Successfully found caregiver with id: " + result.id);
                //result.id shows correct id here!
     

            } else {
                this.setState(({
                    errorStatus: status,
                    error: error
                }));
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: I am little confused, so basically you have a form where the user enter something, and on click of submit button you pass that id to your rest service and it will return the data is that something

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't want the post to get too long.
There is a form, where I write the name of a caregiver. When I click submit, I have this method that will search for that caregiver by name, and retrieve all the details about him. From this, I need only the id.

Comment: Okay half understood form - type name - submit . What is API_USERS is it an API or its a collection of array of of objects

Comment: that's where i have my method for creating the Request to send to the database. I didn't add that since the problem since to be here. It retrieves the id correctly, i just can't seem to use it after the function is over. It might be because of the asynchronous problem pointed out by @Nicholas bellow.

Comment: Oh okay cool, thanks for the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getCaregiverByName is asynchronous. When you call it, the gears are set in motion, but then the function finishes immediately. Then you return to handleSubmit, and log out nothing, because it isn't done yet.

Some time later, the get finishes, and the callback function will be called. Any code that you need to run when the result is ready needs to be done in that callback, or something called by that callback.

So if we're sticking with callbacks, you can add a callback to `findCaregiver`:

```
handleSubmit() {
  let name = this.state.formControls.caregiverName.value;
  this.findCaregiver(name, (id) => {
    console.log("id: " + id);
  });
}

findCaregiver(name, callback) {
  API_USERS.getCaregiverByName(name, (result, status, error) => {
    if (result !== null && (status === 200 || status === 201)) {
      callback(result.id);
    }
  }
}
```

If you perfer promises to callbacks (most people do), you can instead change your code to return a promise. Perhaps getCaregiverByName could be modified to return a promise, but if you don't have access to that code you can wrap your existing code in a promise like this:

```
handleSubmit() {
  let name = this.state.formControls.caregiverName.value;
  this.findCaregiver(name)
    .then((c) => {
      console.log("id: " + c);
    });
}

findCaregiver(name) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    API_USERS.getCaregiverByName(name, (result, status, error) => {
      if (result !== null && (status === 200 || status === 201)) {
        resolve(result.id);
      } else {
        reject(error);
      }
    })
  });
}
```

And if it's returning a promise, you have the option to use async/await:

```
asycn handleSubmit() {
  let name = this.state.formControls.caregiverName.value;
  const c = await this.findCaregiver(name);
  console.log("id: " + c);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! So, I will use the first method, the one without Promise, as it's a bit easier for me to understand it. But now, if I want to save the id in another variable, and use it as any other value in the function how would I do it?

Comment: handleSubmit() {                                                                                                             
  let careid = '';
  let name = this.state.formControls.caregiverName.value;
  this.findCaregiver(name, (id) => {
    careid = id;
  });
}

Comment: this i what i tried, but still, the careid will be empty when I get out of the lambda thingy

Comment: Try putting on the state and use it in the component , Does that work for your case

Comment: That didn't work. But the I tried with the promise method, and that worked! So thank you sooo much. I don't understand it completely, but I'm happy it works and I can read some more on the topic. Thanks a lot!